# Combining functions for string representation of Hashtbl and Map.S in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml, functor, abstraction, redundancy

Simply put, I am trying to make generic functors or functions to create a string form for `Hashtbl` and `Map.S` module types.

I was able to implement such functions on an individual basis, but there is still much redundant code.

Here is what I have as of now:

```ml
let string_of_list (string_of_el: 'a -> string) (lst: 'a list): string =
    List.map string_of_el lst |> String.concat "; " |> Printf.sprintf "[%s]"

let map_ds_fold_func_generator (string_of_key: 'a -> string) (string_of_val: 'b -> string): 'a -> 'b -> string list -> string list =
    let map_fold_func (key: 'a) (value: 'b) (accum: string list): string list =
        (Printf.sprintf "(%s, %s)" (string_of_key key) (string_of_val value))::accum
    in map_fold_func

let string_of_hashtbl (string_of_key: 'a -> string) (string_of_val: 'b -> string) (tbl: ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t): string =
    string_of_list Fun.id (Hashtbl.fold (map_ds_fold_func_generator string_of_key string_of_val) tbl [])

module StringOfMap (M: Map.S) = struct
    let string_of_map string_of_key string_of_val map =
        string_of_list Fun.id (M.fold (map_ds_fold_func_generator string_of_key string_of_val) map [])
end
```

Function explanations:

`string_of_list` is pretty self explanatory. It takes in a function that converts the elements of a `list` to a `string` and a `list` and returns a `string` representation of the `list`.

`map_ds_fold_func_generator`'s purpose is to abstract the function used to fold the `Hashtbl` or `Map.S` structure. `string_of_key` and `string_of_val` are the functions used to convert keys and values, respectively, in key-value pairs of the mapping to `string`s. It then returns the function that can be used to convert the key-value pair to a string and add it to the accumulating list for the fold function.

`string_of_hashtbl` is used to convert a `Hashtbl.t` to a `string`. `string_of_key` and `string_of_val` have the same meaning as above.

`string_of_map` in the `StringOfMap` module is used to convert a `Map.S.t` to a `string`. `string_of_key` and `string_of_val` have the same meaning as above.

Both `string_of_hashtbl` and `string_of_map` have the same function layout:

```ml
let string_of_map_ds string_of_key string_of_val ds =
    string_of_list Fun.id (DS.fold (map_ds_fold_func_generator string_of_key string_of_val) ds [])
```

However, mainly because the definitions for `t` are different, I am struggling to find a way to decrease the redundancy in the very similar function layouts.

Comment: Look into Jane Street's replacement standard library. It includes ppx modules for easy stringification of types.

Comment: Are `map_ds_fold_func_factory` and `map_ds_fold_func_generator` supposed to be the same thing?

Comment: @Shawn Yes. Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses the [`Seq`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/libref/Seq.html) module to do it. Basically, all you need is a function that turns a sequence into a list string, and then call that with the appropriate data structure to sequence conversion (Itself passed as an argument to a higher level function):

```ml
let string_of_list (string_of_el: 'a -> string) (lst: 'a list): string =
    List.map string_of_el lst |> String.concat "; " |> Printf.sprintf "[%s]"

let pair_to_string (string_of_fst: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_snd: 'b -> string) ((fst:'a), (snd:'b)): string =
  let s1 = string_of_fst fst
  and s2 = string_of_snd snd in
  Printf.sprintf "(%s, %s)" s1 s2

let string_of_seq (string_of_fst: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_snd: 'b -> string) (s: ('a * 'b) Seq.t): string =
  List.of_seq s |> string_of_list (pair_to_string string_of_fst string_of_snd)

let string_of_ds (string_of_key: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_val: 'b -> string)
      (to_seq: 'c -> ('a * 'b) Seq.t) (ds:'c): string =
  to_seq ds |> string_of_seq string_of_key string_of_val

let string_of_hashtbl (string_of_key: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_val: 'b -> string) (tbl: ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t): string =
  string_of_ds string_of_key string_of_val Hashtbl.to_seq tbl

module StringOfMap (M: Map.S) = struct
  type key = M.key
  type 'a t = 'a M.t
  let string_of_map (string_of_key: key -> string)
        (string_of_val: 'a -> string) (map: 'a t): string =
    string_of_ds string_of_key string_of_val M.to_seq map
end

module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

let _ =
  let module PrintableMap = StringOfMap(StringMap) in
  let example = [ ("dog", 1); ("cat", 2); ("chicken", 3); ("rat", 4);
                  ("goat", 5)] in
  let htable = List.to_seq example |> Hashtbl.of_seq
  and smap = List.to_seq example |> StringMap.of_seq in
  print_endline (string_of_hashtbl Fun.id Int.to_string htable);
  print_endline (PrintableMap.string_of_map Fun.id Int.to_string smap)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use something that looks more like your version by lifting the almost-duplicate code out into its own function that takes the appropriate module's fold routine as an argument, much like the above does with the `to_seq` functions:

```ml
let string_of_list (string_of_el: 'a -> string) (lst: 'a list): string =
    List.map string_of_el lst |> String.concat "; " |> Printf.sprintf "[%s]"

let map_ds_fold_func_generator (string_of_key: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_val: 'b -> string): 'a -> 'b -> string list -> string list =
    fun key value accum -> (Printf.sprintf "(%s, %s)" (string_of_key key)
                              (string_of_val value))::accum

(* This is why I prefer type inference to explicit typing *)
let string_of_ds (string_of_key: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_val: 'b -> string)
      (fold_fn: ('a -> 'b -> string list -> string list)
       -> 'c -> string list -> string list)
      (ds: 'c): string =
  string_of_list Fun.id
    (fold_fn (map_ds_fold_func_generator string_of_key string_of_val) ds [])

let string_of_hashtbl (string_of_key: 'a -> string)
      (string_of_val: 'b -> string) (tbl: ('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t): string =
  string_of_ds string_of_key string_of_val Hashtbl.fold tbl

module StringOfMap (M: Map.S) = struct
  type key = M.key
  type 'a t = 'a M.t
  let string_of_map (string_of_key: key -> string)
        (string_of_val: 'a -> string) (map: 'a t): string =
    string_of_ds string_of_key string_of_val M.fold map
end

module StringMap = Map.Make(String)

let _ =
  let module PrintableMap = StringOfMap(StringMap) in
  let example = [ ("dog", 1); ("cat", 2); ("chicken", 3); ("rat", 4);
                  ("goat", 5)] in
  let htable = List.to_seq example |> Hashtbl.of_seq
  and smap = List.to_seq example |> StringMap.of_seq in
  print_endline (string_of_hashtbl Fun.id Int.to_string htable);
  print_endline (PrintableMap.string_of_map Fun.id Int.to_string smap)
```